# Firebase messaging doesn't work after app reinstall and launch first time

Tags: ios, iphone

When i delete and reinstall my iOS app after that first launch firebase messaging service is not giving any token. But after second launch i am getting that firebase token.Please help me out this is very important for me to update token.I need this firebase token on first app launch.

**At first launch in console i am getting :->** does not respond to -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:. Please implement -messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken: to be provided with an FCM token. APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes

**At second launch in console i am getting :->** [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled () APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes
Device Token: dO7xSVL0Hj0:APA91bGFH9Oy0EmqPwdtuCJgszWOS8pV5uay2SZd9s9wtbUaHrlpX7wA4BecXO0b

**Token is accurate i just delete half string.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find this function `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)` will call twice after app reinstall and launch first time; You should call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` when the `fcmToken` is not change, so that the device token can match to the `fcmToken`.

In my app, I just call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` in the first view after user log in. Every thing will be ok!